# Keypress enter key does not work in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, chrome

I am replacing the default datepicker for the jquery picker and I have a Javascript code to handle that. I also have a keypress event when I go to the element with tab and press enter it show me the date picker, but in Chrome it does not work, when I press the enter key the event does not fire, and I press another key and it work.

Javascript code

```
//Datepicker jquery ui
        function ImproveDateTextBoxs() {
            $("img[id*=DatePickerImage]").closest(".ms-dtinput").remove();
            $(".ms-dtinput input[id$='Date']").each(function () {
                ImproveDate($(this));
                $($(this).next('img')).wrap($("<A/>").attr("href","#"));



            });
        }

        function ImproveDate(obj) {

//          obj.focus(function () { obj.select(); });

            if (typeof jQuery.ui.datepicker != "undefined") {
                obj.datepicker({
                    showOn: 'button',
                    buttonImage: '/_layouts/images/calendar.GIF',
                    buttonImageOnly: true,
                    showOtherMonths: true,
                        selectOtherMonths: true,
                    showButtonPanel: true,
                    changeMonth: true,
                    changeYear: true,
                    onClose: function() {
                        $(this).next('a').focus(); 
                    }               
                });
                obj.next('a').keypress(function (e) {
                 var key = e.which;
                 if(key == 13)  // the enter key code
                  {
//                  e.preventDefault();
//                  console.log("hola");
                    $(this).children().click();
                    return false;  
                  }
                });
//          obj.parent().next().children("a").removeAttr('onclick');
//          obj.parent().next().children("a").click(function () { obj.select(); });
            }
        }

        $(document).ready(function () {
            ImproveDateTextBoxs()
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

Chrome does not respond to enter key because this event is associate to the href attribute, so I put my javascript inside the href

```
//Datepicker jquery ui
        function ImproveDateTextBoxs() {
            $("img[id*=DatePickerImage]").closest(".ms-dtinput").remove();
            $(".ms-dtinput input[id$='Date']").each(function () {
                ImproveDate($(this));
                var idAnchor = $(this).attr('id') + "Anchor";
                $($(this).next('img')).wrap("<a id='" + idAnchor + "' href='javascript:openJqueryCalendar(\"" + idAnchor + "\");'></a>");
            });
        }

        function openJqueryCalendar(element) {
            $('#'+element).children().click();
        }

        function ImproveDate(obj) {     
            if (typeof jQuery.ui.datepicker != "undefined") {
                obj.datepicker({
                    showOn: 'button',
                    buttonImage: '/_layouts/images/calendar.GIF',
                    buttonImageOnly: true,
                    showOtherMonths: true,
                        selectOtherMonths: true,
                    showButtonPanel: true,
                    changeMonth: true,
                    changeYear: true,
                    onClose: function() {
                        $(this).next('a').focus(); 
                    }               
                });
            }
        }

        $(document).ready(function () {
            ImproveDateTextBoxs()
        });
```